# SCSS Loader DEPRECATION WARNING

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I using scss in my project to import scss files.

For example I have file with variables (that using everywhere in my project)

And I have `desktop.scss` for importing files into it

Like this

```
   @import 'variables';
@import 'desktop/_style';
@import 'desktop/index';
@import 'desktop/step_1';
@import 'desktop/step_2';
@import 'desktop/step_3';
@import 'desktop/step_4';
```

According to this issue

[Link](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2362)

It will be deprecated.

But what I can use instead of it?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is only about importing `CSS` into a `SCSS` file. From your code I assume, that you only use `SCSS` Files, so you won't have a problem with that in future.

Comment: So if I import SCSS  to SCSS m I will not have any problems?

Comment: No, your way is a common way to import scss into scss. You won't have any problems